# Attempting to recreate a sound from track

Tags: sound-design, synthesizer

I have been producing music for some years now but I have never taken steps in learning how to build sounds from the ground up. I am currently practicing by recreating sounds from tracks that I enjoy.

Using Vital, I am trying to recreate the lead sounds in this track:

(timestamped).

So far I have created the following: https://vocaroo.com/11xuI9fReSlu. Using Vital, with the following oscillators:
[image]

And effects:
[image]

As you can hear from the sample there is quite some substance missing to the sound (my sound is a lot softer compared to the original). Now my question would be the following:

Which basic oscillator (sine, saw, square) would approach this sound best (if any)? Are there perhaps effects I am missing with which I can approach this sound better?

Answer (score 2):

That's not bad actually, a very good start.

But I would try layering another note on top. Saw-based, try an octave down (or maybe one saw vco an octave down) to open up that saw-buzz that you're missing. High-pass/EQ the new saw to keep mostly the mid-to-high brightness and fuzz it up a bit with some fuzzy feedback distortion effect (try to get it to self-oscillate slightly). *Maybe* low-pass the sound you have *slightly* to allow for the fuzzy saw to bite through (or lower the high shelf on the EQ).

I've found these days, it's all about layering and big-effects, filling out the spectrum and space. Make it interesting with different attack rates. Most people starting out forget the effects, so it's dry and "small", but you have a good start on the chorus and reverb on this one.

But... *bigger* reverb. Very bright and spacey 8th delayed reverb and 1/4 note delay. I think this is 3 sounds, actually. There's a wide stab on the first note of every bar.
Just noticed, you can hear the 3rd sound at around 34 secs on its own.

A good tip is to record the sound you're trying to recreate to a track in the DAW so you can quickly listen whenever you want.